# How to send one value from a while loop and display another value in text box using php

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to display one value and send another value at the same time in Input text field?

I have a form which displaying details in descending order and when i updating the details from another page it's updating in ascending order.

**Code:**

```
$sql4 = "select * from staffing where p_id='$p_id' order by staffing_no desc"; 
$result4 = mysql_query($sql4);
while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
    <input type="text" name="staffing_issues[]" value="<?php echo $staffing_issues;?>" /> 
}
```

**Another Page:**

```
$staffing_issues = $_POST['staffing_issues'];
$count = count($staffing_issues);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { 
    $staffing_issues=$_POST['staffing_issues'][$i];
    $sql="select * from staffing where p_id='$p_id' and Staffing_no='$i' order by Staffing_no asc";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $id=$row['id'];
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){

    $update="update staffing set staffing_issues='$staffing_issues' where id='$id'";
    $update=mysql_query($update);
    } 
}
```

Now it's updating in ascending order My requirement is to update it in desc order.

Comment: Anything is possible. Please provide any code you have already written, along with any specific problems you are having.

Comment: add hidden field in the form before submit the page

Comment: @user3317777 - could you please edit that code into your question? It's very hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below :

```
<form action="actionname" method="post">

     <input type="text" value="Hello" name="txtHello"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="Hi" name="txtHi"/>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit"/>

</form>
```